# Python: Adding within lists

Tags: python, arrays, list, sum, sublist

It may be the fact I haven't slept yet, but I can't find the solution to this problem, so I come to you all. I have a list, with a series of sub-lists, each containing two values, like so:

```
list = (
  (2, 5),
  (-1, 4),
  ( 7, -3)
  )
```

I also have a variable, a similar list with two values, that is as such:

```
var = (0, 0)
```

I want to add all the x values in *list*, then all the y values, and then store the sums in *var*, so the desired value of *var* is:

```
var = (8, 6)
```

How could I do it? I apologize if the answer is something stupid simple, I just need to get this done before I can sleep.

Answer (score 6):

```
sumvar = map(sum,zip(*my_list))
```

should do what you want i think

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a job for "reduce" to me:

```
reduce(lambda a,b: (a[0]+b[0],a[1]+b[1]), list)
(8,6)
```

you could also use another list comprehension method, (a bit more readable):

```
sum(a for a,b in tpl), sum(b for a,b in tpl)
(8,6)
```